# Is this young plant a rosemary?

Tags: identification, herbs, rosemary

Since the last rain, this plant has been making its way in our garden.

It looks like a rosemary, it is growing a couple feet from an old rosemary bush, and its tender leaves *kinda* taste like one. We're not quite sure it is one, though.

Is it a rosemary, or something else?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please exercise caution when tasting plants if you are not 100% sure what they are or if they're safe to eat.
You should be able to use your sense of smell as even young rosemary plants release the odour when the leaves are rubbed or crushed. In my experience rosemary tends to grow more upright than what you have shown and the ends of the 'branches' seem to have a slightly different arrangement to what I would expect of rosemary.

Comment: @Alpar thank you! I'll bear your safety advice in mind, I had already naively ingested a leaf or two, will be more careful now.

Answer (score 4):

It looks more like a young Helichrysum italicum than Rosemary, but since that's the curry plant, meaning it smells of curry when you bruise the leaves, it shouldn't be hard to tell. It's not toxic to eat, but does not impart a curry flavour to food - the flowers are yellow, and the oil from those is used as a herbal remedy for various things.